# DLL not found in .EXE path

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I've written a .dll wrapper in c++ that uses the API of an old customer .dll, which then gets used by a program written in VB. It all works perfectly fine, but on some machines for some reason I don't understand I get an "DLL not found exception" (0x80070035) even though all DLLs are in the .EXE startup path. It works on my machine, it works on some other machines as well, but then on yet another I get the exception, even though all are running Win7 x64.

Copying my DLLs inot System32 doesn't resolve the issue, and to be honest I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are the DLLs at the same locations as the EXE? and how do you run the exe? have you got the name of the missing DLL?

Comment: Yes the 2 DLLs (my wrapper + the client one) are in the exact same folder as my EXE. It's just a small standalone program so I just execute the EXE, tried it with admin rights and all but it didn't change the issue. The missing DLL is my self-written wrapper DLL, all the system DLLs are loaded up correctly.

Comment: That is ERROR_BAD_NETPATH, "The network path was not found".  Protecting yourself against a wonky and unreliable network is not possible.  Your user's IT staff needs to fix that.  Just tell them what the error means.  Their simplest workaround for them is to deploy your app locally, copying the files to the C: drive.

Comment: Sorry for expressing myself poorly, the app is always executed locally and not from a network path. The entire folder goes onto the C: drive where it should work, but sometimes it just doesn't.

Comment: Nonetheless, something is performing network access, and then failing with "0x80070035: The network path was not found"

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem to be honest, the program is required to run offline. Running my tests offline without any network connection and it works, same on another device and it works, but then on a 3rd it fails.

Comment: *the program is required to run offline.* -- That doesn't mean that the program doesn't have some sort of hidden network access API call, and up to this point, it worked on those other machines without you being aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll bet that the DLL which is not found is not *your* DLL, but some other DLL which it links to.  Run your copy of [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (*), load your DLL into that, and see which DLLs it links to.  There will be a surprisingly large number, and the customer sites with problems will be missing one of them.

(Just to add to the fun, it could be that your DLL links to a second DLL which needs a third DLL - and it is that *third* DLL which is missing.)

*: You have *got* a copy of `depends.exe` haven't you?  It's an absolutely essential tool for debugging all sorts of problems.

Comment: Hmm.  I think this answer is wrong - Hans Passant has pointed out in the comments that 0x80070035 is a networking issue, not a simple "File not Found".  I'll leave the answer up, because it might help someone else, even if it's not the answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the idea anyway, I'm not sure if it's the wrong idea, I tried that as well. Sadly the DLLs are dynamically loaded a lot later so Depends can't find them.

Comment: @afi70: No, Depends is definitely the right tool. It can also handle dynamically loaded DLL's. However, that means you need to actually run the executable from within Depends (obviously, as the DLL's loaded can depend on program input).

Comment: @MSalters: Ooo! I'd forgotten about that capability.  Worth remembering.